# Passing values from views.py to a template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Maybe this is a very silly question, but I'm new to django. 
My application doesn't require the use of any database, so my models.py is empty.My application receives a POST request from a template which is handled in my views.py and the response is another template.How can I pass values from views.py to my new template (Without using the database)?

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext


def search_isbn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x=500
    return render_to_response('results.html',RequestContext(request))
```

I wish to pass the value x to results.html.How can I do that ?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Reading the FineManual might be a good start - it's all documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a dictionary that contains the variables you want to pass.

```
def search_isbn(request):
    x = 0 # Without this, you will get NameError if request.method is not 'POST'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = 500
    return render_to_response('results.html', RequestContext(request, {'x': x}))
    #                                                                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `render` function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def search_isbn(request):
    x = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x=500
    return render('results.html', {'x':x})
```