# How do we pass values - from a list in views.py - to html

Tags: django, python-3.x, for-loop, django-templates, django-views

I read all the applicable django documentation (tag templates, classes, for loop, how to receive the values from list, dict etc.) and set-up a small project to learn more about Django, and python.

**My problem is clear as crystal:** why is the function defined in views.py not passing the argument to the .html file (while receiving zero errors)

**Goal**: Fill my html template with image-blocks for each value in list[], or dict{'x':x}. The dictionairy is made out of 3 dictionairies:

```
Dict { 

      1 {
          X: '1', '2', '3'
      }, 

      2 {
          X: '1', '2', '3'
      },

      3 {
          X: '1', '2', '3'
      },
}
```

all Dict.keys contain urls as strings '/folder/folder/image.png' which will be used in the src='' tag in the html).

Based on what i've read the code for my loop in .html would be (i.e. for a list):

```
{% for value in list %}             
    <div id ="Menu-Item">
        <div id ="Menu-Item-Wrap">
            <img scr ={{ value}}>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried, and tried, but even passing a single value from a list with 1 value does not seem to work. There are no errors found, and i am able to view the page. However without any of the divs inside a loop, or with divs and a `<p>`, but without the `{{ Single_Val_From_List }}`.

I checked the following (relevant) information for me:

[Passing values from views.py to a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771543/passing-values-from-views-py-to-a-template)

[How to render image in my Django Blog Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488284/how-to-render-image-in-my-django-blog-template)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-tag-reference

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/template-response/

Views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
import pandas as pd
from os import walk
import pathlib
from django.db import models


# Create your views here.
def smaakjes_list(request):
    return render(request, 'smaakjes/smaakjes.html')

def index(request):
    x = ["LaLaLaa", "dad", "dd"]
    return render(request, 'smaakjes/smaakjes.html', {'FrisDrank' : x})
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>de smaakjes</title>
        {% load static %}
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stylesheet.css' %}"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="Main-Content">

            <div id="Top-Content">
                <h1 class="hero_header">Bestel Menu</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="Content">
                <div id="List-Content">

                    <div id ="Content-List">
                            <div id ="Title-Box">
                                <h1 class="hero_header">Frisdranken</h1>
                            </div>              
                            <div id ="Menu-Item">
                                <div id ="Menu-Item-Wrap">
                                    {% for value in FrisDrank %}
                                        <p>{{ value }}</p>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div id='Footer-Top-Bar'></div>
        <div id='Footer-Main'></div>

    </footer>
</html>
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import pathlib



urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.smaakjes_list),
    url(r'^$', views.index),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two URLs pointing to the same view. Only `smaakjes_list` will ever be called; it does not pass a list (or any variables at all). `index` will never ever be used.

I'm not sure why you have done this. Give your views separate URLs. Or just delete the `smaakjes_list` view and its corresponding URL pattern.

Comment: thanks for that. I removed the index in the URLs, and it indeed had no effect on this all. Not sure how to delete the post?  since - and i am not sure why - the content of my dictionary is being rendered. I am rendering a d{'1' : [], '2' : []}. But cannot iterate through the keys (i.e. 2). I can through the values (i.e. 0).